# Portable Webserver Filter

Tags: c++, c, apache, web-services, nginx

I am working on a project that involves modifying (not generating) content as it flows through a webserver, and would like a portable way to do this.

For the sake of discretion, let's say this project automatically minifies the HTML/JS/CSS before it goes out to the client (this is not actually what the project does, but is close enough to understand the basic concept).

Currently, we use a different module for each webserver; this approach works fine for a small number of closely related web servers (Apache and Nginx ironically have very similar API's that can be easily wrapped), but obviously this approach will become more and more untenable as the project expands.

So, I am looking for a light weight approach, one that:

1. Does not require the filter to load the content itself (full webservers are much better at this than I).
2. Does not require the filter to transmit the content to the end client (same as above)
3. Is portable between (at least) major web servers

The first requirement strikes out my filter being a content generator and the second strikes out being an HTTP filter. I had looked into FastCGI, but it's filter mode is not widely supported (if I am wrong, or there is an easy way to configure FastCGI as a filter on most web servers, this is preferred). SCGI looks easy enough, but I can find no documentation on using SCGI modules as filters.

Is there a portable and light weight solution to providing a web server filter?

Comment: If you have resource restrictions maybe it is good idea to look into nginx solution? nginx also have a good filering options, CGI and plugin support.

Comment: @Tanuki I want to make a filter that runs on multiple web servers, not embed that filter into nginx and use it as a proxy.

Comment: You can write a filter with configuration in one database, then run multiple instances of the database using same preferences.

Comment: @Tanuki What? How does that in any way solve my question, which is making a portable filter?

Comment: In fact the thing that you need already exists and called squeed. In squeed you can apply almost any kind of filters. But if you want to roll your own you have 2 choices: native module or CGI (any flavour). I suggest you to peek up the simplest and write your app. If the speed of that won't be enough or it will eat a lot of resources - you can always replace it with better solution.

Comment: @Tanuki CGI cannot do this; CGI only supports "responder" role, not "filter".

Comment: Did you read that: http://python.ca/scgi/protocol.txt?

Comment: If you will not find the docs - you can unpack apache sources and dive into the modules/proxy/scgi.h and modules/proxy/scgi.c.

Comment: So you want the server to say: "here is the data I'm about to send", then your filter says: "wait, let me take a look first ... no, use this..." and the server then sends the filtered data.  It's not difficult for cgi to just get the data, filter and send it though.

Comment: For cgi you can use the REQUEST_URI for the file, then the QUERY_STRING (an environment variable that contains the portion of the url after `?`) for any filter options.  Do your filtering and write your http header and then your filtered data to stdout. There are helper libraries for this(cgic is the 1st that comes to mind)

Comment: Have you considered writing your own server layer for your filter application? Apache, NGINX etc all have some kind of custom hooks for filtering, writing some abstraction code  while can be difficult is not impossible. You also get full control over what you consider "lowest common denominator".

Comment: Can you simply use Nginx with your filter module as a reverse web proxy?  It is famous for high performance for such a usage.  Seems like you already have a working filter for Ngnix.  You only need to selectively pass specified types of contents to the module by configuring Nginx.

Answer (score 2):

I think your best option is to use a TCP proxy which can be cross OS standalone compilable and sits in front (or behind) of any webserver. You can design your own filter mechanism inside this.
Looking for an add-in which works with all webservers takes a lot of development.